# Using method source(edge) of Package Graphs.jl in Julia on Juliabox.org

Tags: graph, runtime-error, julia

Take a look at the following simple code example:

```
Pkg.add("Graphs")
using Graphs

gd = simple_graph(20, is_directed=true) # directed graph with 20 nodes
nodeTo = 2
for nodeFrom in vertices(gd) # add some edges...
    if(nodeTo != 20)
       add_edge!(gd, nodeFrom, nodeTo)
        nodeTo +=1
    end
end
for i in edges(gd) # Print source and target for every edge in gd
    println("Target: ",target(i))
    println("Source: ", source(i))
end
```

So it works sometimes, and it prints the source and targets of the edges, but most times running the cell(after programming in this or other cells or doing nothing) i get the following error:

```
type: anonymous: in apply, expected Function, got Int64
while loading In[11], in expression starting on line 14

 in anonymous at no file:16
```

I have not change any code concerning the method nether the cell, but it doesnt work anymore. The method target(edge) works fine, but the method source(edge) makes problems the most times.
http://graphsjl-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/graphs.html#graph 
What should i do? I would be pleased to get some help.

After some thoughts, i found out, that the mistake have to be in the code between the hashtags:

```
Pkg.add("JuMP")
Pkg.add("Cbc")
# Pkg.update()
using Graphs
using JuMP
using Cbc

function createModel(graph, costs, realConnections)
    m = Model(solver = CbcSolver())
    @defVar(m, 0 <= x[i=1:realConnections] <= 1, Int)
    @setObjective(m, Min, dot(x,costs[i=1:realConnections]))
    println(m)
    for vertex in vertices(graph)
        edgesIn = Int64[] # Array of edges going in the vertex
        edgesOut = Int64[] # Array of Edges going out of the vertex
        for edge in edges(graph)
            if (target(edge) == vertex) # works fine
                push!(edgesIn, edge_index(edge))

            end
            if (source(edge) == vertex) # does not work
                push!(edgesOut, edge_index(edge))
                print(source(edge), " ")
            end

        end
#         @addConstraint(m, sum{x[edgesIn[i]], i=1:length(edgesIn)} - sum{x[edgesOut[j]], j=1:length(edgesOut)} == 0)   
    end
    return m
end


file = open("csp50.txt")
g = createGraph(file) # g = g[1] = simpleGraph Object with 50 nodes and 173 arccs, g[2] = number of Nodes g[3]/g[4] = start/end time g[5] = costs of each arc


# After running this piece of code, the source(edge) method does not work anymore
########################################################################################
# adding a source and sink node and adding edges between every node of the orginal graph and the source and sink node
realConnections = length(g[5]) # speichern der Kanten
source = (num_vertices(g[1])+1)
sink = (num_vertices(g[1])+2)
add_vertex!(g[1], source) 
add_vertex!(g[1], sink) 
push!(g[3], 0) 
push!(g[3], 0)
push!(g[4], 0) 
push!(g[4], 0)
for i in vertices(g[1])
    if (i != source)
        add_edge!(g[1], source, i) # edge from source to i
        push!(g[5], 0)
    end
    if (i != sink)
        add_edge!(g[1], i, sink) # Kante von i zu Senke
        push!(g[5], 0) # Keine Kosten/Zeit fuer diese Kante
    end
end
######################################################################################
numEdges = num_edges(g[1]);
createModel(g[1], g[5], realConnections)
```

Comment: I believe the `Graphs` package is [by default installed on JuliaBox](https://github.com/JuliaLang/JuliaBox/blob/master/PACKAGES.md).  If you remove `Pkg.add("Graphs")`, do the symptoms change?  Is your entire codeblock above in one cell, or split into multiple cells?

Comment: If i remove `Pkg.add("Graphs")`, the symptoms are still there. My whole Code is in three different Cells:
1. Just a function creating a graph object
2. code that use the graph object and creates an optimization model. In this cell i use the source method
3. The cell with the code example above.   

I found out, that when i restart the Kernel, i can run the third cell (the example above), but after run the second cell the problem appears and i can not run the second neither the third cell, which use this method

Comment: Would you post some code (per cell) that demonstrates the problem?  I can't replicate the error.

Comment: Looks like you may be playing with fire here.  If you replace your **variable** `source` with `my_source`, do you experience the same problem?

Comment: With your original code, did you get a warning, something like, `Warning: imported binding for source overwritten ...`?

Comment: Tank you very much for yout help! This was exactly the problem. I did not notice, that "source" was a reserved expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Julia's Manual](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/variables/):

> Julia will even let you redefine built-in constants and functions if
>   needed:
>
> ```
> julia> pi
> π = 3.1415926535897...
>
> julia> pi = 3
> Warning: imported binding for pi overwritten in module Main
> 3
>
> julia> pi
> 3
>
> julia> sqrt(100)
> 10.0
>
> julia> sqrt = 4
> Warning: imported binding for sqrt overwritten in module Main
> 4
> ```
>
> However, this is obviously not recommended to avoid potential
>   confusion.

So reusing `source` as a variable "unbound" it from it's function definition.  Using a different variable name should preserve the `Graphs.jl` definition for it.